# How can i convert base64 data into image in my view when populate from my database and also reset it?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have HTML code like below :

```
<tr class="form-group" >
                        <td>
                            Picture 
                        </td>
                        <td>
                           <img ng-src="data:image/jpeg;base64,{{data.Picture}}" ng-model="p1" id="photo-id" height=120 width=200 style="border:2px solid black" />
                            <input type="file" name="file" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().uploadFile(this)" ng-model="p2" id="photo-upload" />

                        </td>

                    </tr>
```

And also have the function :

```
$scope.uploadFile = function (input) {
            if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function (e) {
                   $('#photo-id').attr('src', e.target.result);
                    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
                    var imageElement = document.createElement("img");

                    imageElement.setAttribute('src', e.target.result);
                    canvas.width = imageElement.width;
                    canvas.height = imageElement.height;
                    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
                    context.drawImage(imageElement, 0, 0);
                    var base64Image = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");

                    $scope.Picture = base64Image.replace(/data:image\/jpeg;base64,/g, '');
                }
                reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
            }
        };
```

Submitting this is fine. But How can i reset it after submit and how can i populate it for edit? When i want to populate, i have the binary data, How can i convert that data into image in view page?

Comment: Populate what for edit? Edit what? It's not likely you want to edit the base64?

Comment: Want to edit the image,,,and image come from my database,,,where it saved as a binary data,,,,,So if i click the edit button i need the image not the binary data.... That means somehow/somewhere i need to convert binary data to image,,,,,,

Comment: Just display the image using base64 in src and let user upload a new one to replace it

Comment: Solved,,,,,Edit can be possible using src as said by charlietfl (Thanks for that),,, and reset is possible easily as :                                                    For Picture:     $('#photo-id').attr('src', '');
and for File :    $('#photo-upload').attr('value', '');